# I am looking for structure alignment when pointers are embedded in structures, I have found interesting links but not what I want

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows64

I am passing a structure from application to the driver through deviceiocontrol function.

The structure has only two members.

```
struct Buff
{
   BYTE * bPtr;
   UINT   uiSize; 
}BuffVar;
```

I assign a pointer and size and pass the address of the structure to the driver.

On the driver I create pointers to the structure (I have the structure shared between app and driver) and access the values from the user passed buffer. When I access the pointer I get the correct value, but the size value is always a junk data. It is a 64bit platform I am working with. When I compile the application with WDK, it works perfectly, when I use visual studio I face this problem. I m new to this environment. Has any one faced such kind of issue? Any help is highly appreciated.

Regards,
Abhiram

Comment: I can't help with drivers and/or WDK, but perhaps comparing sizeof() and offsetof() on the client side and driver side will shed some light.  Try: `sizeof(struct Buff)` and `offsetof(Buff, uiSize)`